# Requestmapping from angular-ui-router and spring mvc

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security, angular-ui-router

I am using AngulaJS as a javascript client side and spring mvc as a rest backend.
In AngulaJS i am using ui-router.

Here is config.js file

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index");
    $stateProvider
        .state('trains', {
            url: "/trains",
            templateUrl: "views/pages/trains.html",
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Trains'
            }
        })
```

Below is html file (left-sliderbar.html

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
    <a href="javascript:;" ui-sref="trains" title="the trains">Trains </a>
 </li>
```

The problem is when I clicked on "Trains" menu in left left-sliderbar, I cannot get request mapping with the method in  Rest Backend of Spring MVC. Below is code from Controller of Spring MVC

```
@RequestMapping("/trains")
    public String getTrainPartialPage(ModelMap modelMap) {
        System.out.println("---------Request Mapping: /trains: " + this.getClass());
        return "pages/trains";
    }
```

Please help me to fix it out, I'd like to use ui-router than ngRoute, thanks you

Answer (score 0):

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index");
$stateProvider
    .state('trains', {
        url: "/trains",
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Trains'
        },views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: "views/pages/trains.html",
                    controller: 'TrainsController'
                }
            }
    })
```

and you need to implement the  rest calls in your service or in your TrainsController.

Comment: Thanks you, It's hard to explain to you. But I am also using spring security, after login successful it's redirect to main.html file. So that I only get the request mapping for the main. 
[code]
@RequestMapping("/main") 
public void getMainPage() { System.out.println("Main Page"); return;
 } 
[/code]
For example the url below I only get request mapping for main, not for trains. localhost:8080/main#/trains

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a same context.

I think you shoud try to use `templateUrl: "views/pages/trains"` instead of `templateUrl: "views/pages/trains.html"` in your `$stateProvider` provider.

The back-end controller should expose this request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/train")
public ModelAndView getMain() {
    return new ModelAndView("pages/train");
}
```

NB: Using `ModelAndView` as a return object instead of `String` (didn't worked with `String` and actually I con't figure why).

Angular UI Router will write `/train` in the url and Spring will serve the html file mapped on the `/train` route.

Hope will help you.