# Angular ui router and Spring Mvc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am studying the ui router in AngularJs and how does it work together with Spring Mvc as per the documentations and other tutorials I setup my configuration just like this:

```
angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    $stateProvider

        .state('registrationForm',{
            url:'/register',
            templateUrl:'/WEB-INF/html/welcome/registration.html'
        });
});
```

but the registration.html cannot be found by the browser. Then I saw this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202434/requestmapping-from-angular-ui-router-and-spring-mvc) I also tried the suggested solution by still getting the same results. Then I tried to replace the path of the html page on the templateUrl to the @RequestMapping of Spring which is:

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String getRegistrationPage(Model uiModel,WebRequest request){
    RegistrationForm form = new RegistrationForm();
    uiModel.addAttribute("registrationForm", form);
    return "welcome/registration";
}
```

suddenly it works, I am confused because for me it is somehow bit confusing to what the documentation states. Is this the expected outcome of the config file?

Comment: Angular not resolving the view as it needs the `context root` of application to resolve the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS is a purely client based framework, since it's running only in the browser. So Angular doesn't know about any filepaths on the server, it can only communicate through the public URLs of any resources of the server.

Comment: you mean that when I used the Spring Request Mapping on the templateUrl is ok?